# Rewrite SOAP xml before sen it as request

Tags: python, xml, soap, elementtree

I need to rewrite a SOAP XML file before make a request.
I can send the request and receive the response without any issue using a static file, but I need to change some values
I try using ElementTree to manipulate the file but I can't find the tag and value.

The file have the next format:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bbs:QueryDRRequestMsg>
         <RequestHeader>
                    ...
                </RequestHeader>
         <QueryDRRequest>
            <!--Optional:-->
             <bbs:SubAccessCode>
               <bbc:PrimaryIdentity>56795810005</bbc:PrimaryIdentity>
            </bbs:SubAccessCode>
            <bbs:TimePeriod>
               <bbs:StartTime>20150901010000</bbs:StartTime>
               <bbs:EndTime>20150930010000</bbs:EndTime>
            </bbs:TimePeriod>
            <bbs:TotalDRNum>2</bbs:TotalCDRNum>
            <bbs:BeginRowNum>0</bbs:BeginRowNum>
            <bbs:FetchRowNum>10</bbs:FetchRowNum>
         </QueryDRRequest>
      </bbs:QueryDRRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to change the values for the tags

> bbc:PrimaryIdentity

and

> bbs:StartTime

The values will be taken from a html form and with that data rewrite the file before send the file as request.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ElementTree.iter to see the complete text for the tags, like this

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("filexml")
root = tree.getroot()

for child_root in root.iter():
    print  child_root.tag, child_root.attrib
```

This way you will see the complete tag of the elements of the xml file.

And to modify your file, you can try this

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for child_root in root.iter('{http://some_tag}PrimaryIdentity'):
    new_identity = "111111111"
    child_root.text = new_identity
    child_root.set('update','yes')

tree.write('output.xml')
```